# econnrefused 127.0.0.1:5672 Rabbit-mq with docker compose

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, docker-compose

I am not able to connect a node.js app with rabbit-mq server. Postgres is correctly connected. I don't know why I have a connection refused.

```
version: "3"
networks:
app-tier:
  driver: bridge

services:
db:
  image: postgres
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=dockerDBuser
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dockerDBpass
    - POSTGRES_DB=performance
  ports:
    - "5433:5432"
  volumes:
    - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  networks:
    - app-tier

rabbitmq:
  image: rabbitmq:3.6.14-management
  healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://127.0.0.1:5672"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
  ports:
    - "0.0.0.0:5672:5672"
    - "0.0.0.0:15672:15672"
  networks:
    - app-tier
app:
  build: .
  depends_on:
    - rabbitmq
    - db
  links:
    - rabbitmq
    - db
  command: npm run startOrc
  environment:
    DATABASE_URL: postgres://dockerDBuser:dockerDBpass@db:5432/asdf
  restart: on-failure
  networks:
    - app-tier
```

It seems it's trying to connect to the host rabbitmq instead of the container rabbitmq

Comment: You have a DATABASE_URL for postgres but you don't have a QUEUE_URL (or something like this) for RabbitMq.  What url are you using to connect to RabbitMQ.

Comment: @Sodala that would be really helpful, but until the moment I didn't find it

Comment: You didn't find the url of rabbitmq that your application is using ?

Comment: I have found it's connecting to "amqp://0.0.0.0:5672" which is the env variable CLOUDAMQP_URL. The thing is that it's not connecting from the container to the host. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try changing env variable `CLOUDAMQP_URL` to `amqp://rabbitmq:5672`

You can call service by it's name i.e `rabbitmq`.

Comment: That was it..!!

Answer (score 1):

This error also comes up if you haven't started docker and run rabbitmq server. So if in case if someone who's reading this post gets the same error, please check whether your rabbitmq server is running.

You can use below command to run the rabbitmq server. (5672 is the port of that server)

`docker run -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq`

Answer (score 0):

Rabbitmq-service takes time to start, so it better to restart those container who are depend on rabbitmq-service or setTimeout in our service to start connection

if you define depends-on in `docker-compose` then it does't mean our service will start after rabbitmq-service

please suggest, if you have better solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).